# How to define __hash__ when an object can be equal to different kind of objects?

Tags: python, hash

In Python doscumentation, we can read about `__hash__` function :

> The only required property is that objects which compare equal have
>   the same hash value.

I have an object which can be equal to other object of the same type, or to strings:

```
class MyClass:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self.x == other
        if isinstance(other, MyClass):
            return id(self) == id(other)
        return False
```

Having this `__eq__` function, how could I define a valid `__hash__` function ?

**Warning**: Here, `MyClass()` objects are mutable, and `self.x` could change !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define a consistent hash. First, your class does not define `__eq__` consistently; it is not guaranteed that if `x == y` and `y == z`, then `x == z`. Second, your object is mutable. In Python, mutable objects are not supposed to be hashable.

> If a class defines mutable objects and implements a `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` method, it should not implement `__hash__()`, since hashable collection implementations require that a object’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).

Example of broken `==`:

```
x = MyClass('foo')
y = 'foo'
z = MyClass('foo')

x == y # True
y == z # True
x == z # False
```

Comment: This can be fixed by using `self.x == other.x` instead of `id()`. But indeed it won't change the fact that it's not hashable. Ok so I'll have to find an other way to do what I want. Thank you.

Comment: @ThibautD, you still _can_ define `__hash__()`.  The docs are mostly warning about that, if you do define `__hash__()` for mutable objects, hash-based collections (like dicts and sets) containing your objects may not work right.  But you didn't say whether you intend to use these objects as (say) dict keys.

Comment: @TimPeters Yes, the goal is to use them in a set/dict because I have performance issues with big list of these objects when using the 'in' check.

Comment: Then think about making them immutable ;-)  So long as they're mutable, you can't even, e.g., put them in a sorted list and use `bisect` to search.  If the value of an object can change at any time, there's *nothing* you can do better than a linear search (which `in` does).