# Mutable user defined types and sets

Tags: python, hash

I have a use case that requires me to create a set of mutable type
objects, something like this:

```
class abc(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = set(["a"])
    def __eq__(self, o):
        return self.a == o.a
a = abc()
b = abc()
print hash(a)
print hash(b)
print a == b
set([a]) == set([b])
```

Reading the python docs, it says

> "objects which compare equal have the same hash value"

and

> "If a class defines mutable objects and implements a `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` method, it should not implement `__hash__()`, since hashable collection implementations require that a object’s hash value is immutable"

The example above will print true for equality and different integer hashes for both a and b, but false for the set equality. The docs suggest setting the object to be unhashable, but then I can't insert it in a set. Is my usage incorrect?

Are sets in python not meant to be used with mutable types?

Comment: I *think* you mean to ask the same as in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832171/how-to-define-hash-when-an-object-can-be-equal-to-different-kind-of-objects

Comment: @torek So, I can't use mutable objects with sets ? do I need to implement my own set type?

Comment: See [Alex Hall's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33196203/1256452).  Basically you must avoid changing the object while something (whether that's a set, or a dictionary, or whatever) is depending on the object's hash value.  His method 4 (remove and reinsert) works in Python, for instance.  But in short, yes, and this is why `frozenset` exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you insert an object into a set (or any hash-based data structure in any language) and then mutate it, things will break because the new hash value may no longer correspond to its position in the array. So for example if you inserted another object which is equal to the previous object after the mutation, python probably won't be able to find the previous object and it will let both exist in the set. The same applies to a binary search tree.

You need to either:

1. Make your class immutable by only allowing their values to be set in the constructor.
2. Make a second immutable version of your class which the first can be converted to (e.g. by converting the sets to frozensets and hiding access to members).
3. Use a data structure such as a list where you can mutate objects freely but checking for membership (and hence avoiding duplicates) takes O(n) time.
4. Make your object hashable but be extremely careful about it: every mutation which affects its hash and equality must instead remove it from all sets (and dictionaries where it's a key), mutate it, and then put it back.